# How to set Redis max memory?

Tags: redis

I find the configure in [this](http://redis.io/topics/config), it just said the command to use the specify configure:

```
./redis-server <path>/redis.conf
```

But,I have no idea about how to write the configure. So I have find the default configure in [this](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf). But, I still don't understand how to set max memory. Does it just add this line in configure?

```
maxmemory 2mb
```

By the way, I want to know how much the default memory is. and I want to set the memory to 2GB, how to do it?

Then, I have added this line to the redis configure to set maxmemory to 40GB:

```
maxmemory 41943040
```

And I use the command in redis-cli:

```
config get maxmemory
```

it show me:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "41943040"
```

But, my java program throw the exception like this when key number is about 200000:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-228" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:117)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:196)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.hmset(Jedis.java:644)
    at cn.ict.dt2redis.analyser.AbstractAnalyser.pushOne(AbstractAnalyser.java:21)
    at cn.ict.dt2redis.analyser.BatchAbstractAnalyser.run(BatchAbstractAnalyser.java:16)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have no idea about it, do I success in setting max memory to 40 GB? How to do it? please give me some code in detail.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Yes - to set the memory limit just uncomment the `maxmemory` line in the .conf file. The default is 0, which means unlimited (until the operating system runs out of RAM and kills the process - I recommend to always set maxmemory to a sane value).

Updated: as @Eric Uldall mentioned in the comments, a `CONFIG SET maxmemory <sane value>`, followed by a `CONFIG REWRITE` should also do the trick. This will modify your redis.conf to preserve changes in case of restart

Comment: I have added the line "maxmemory 41943040" to set max memory 40GB,but it throw exception "OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'."

Comment: You've set maxmemory to 41943040 bytes = 40960KB = 40MB

Comment: Oh,I see. I have changed to "maxmemory 40gb" to test. Thanks!

Comment: It's also worth noting. If you run `config rewrite` after `config set [key] [value]` it will commit the changes to your redis.conf so it will be preserved in the event of a restart.

Comment: @EricUldall very true :)

Comment: can we set max memory on a set in redis?

Comment: No, it is not possible to limit individual keys' values

Comment: @ItamarHaber Is it possible to do the same on AWS ElasticCache/Redis Cluster? Thanks

Comment: @YairNevet IDK - I work for Redis Labs, home of Open Source Redis and Redis Cloud :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber Okay, Thanks :)

Answer (score 41):

The documentation in the comments call out bytes but I've used extensions such as mb & gb without any issues.

```
$ grep ^maxmemory /etc/redis-server.conf
maxmemory 8gb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

And to confirm:

```
$ redis-cli
...
127.0.0.1:6379> config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "8589934592"
```

Answer (score 19):

> No need of changing any thing in the .conf file just follow the following steps

**Step 1:** First check whether redis-server is working or not

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
```

if the reply is `PONG` then your server is working absolutely fine.

**Step 2:** To get the current max memory run the following commands:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> config get maxmemory
1) "maxmemory"
2) "0"
```

> Initially it is set to 0 by default.

**Step 3:** After running the above step run the following commands to set the maxmemory:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config set maxmemory 128M
OK
```

To check whether the maxmemory is set to 128M run `step 2` again.

**Step 4:** After changing the maxmemory restart the redis-server

```
$ sudo systemctl restart redis
OR
$ sudo systemctl restart redis-server
```

Answer (score 8):

> maxmemory 41943040

option set in bytes, so you set 40MB

Answer (score 3):

Since this is an old question, users who are reading in 2019 and using Ubuntu 18.04, the configuration file is located in `/etc/redis/redis.conf` and if you have installed using (default/recommended method) `apt install redis-server` the default memory limit is set to "0" which practically means there is "no limit" which can be troublesome if user has limited/small amount of RAM/memory. To set your custom memory limit you may simply edit configuration file and type "maxmemory 1gb" as the very first line. Restart redis service for changes to take effect. To verify changes use `redis-cli config get maxmemory`

Ubuntu 18.04 users may read more here: [How to install and configure REDIS on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.furqansiddiqui.com/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having trouble setting the `maxmemory` config setting in a local environment, the actual steps are as follows:

1. In a terminal, start your redis instance `redis-server`
2. In a *new terminal window* run `redis-cli`
3. In the new terminal window (step 2) run `config set maxmemory 2mb`
4. Verify `maxmemory` by running `config get maxmemory` in same terminal window as steps 2/3

Somewhat documented [here](https://redis.io/topics/config) under the **Changing Redis configuration while the server is running** section

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maxmemory option. Be aware though, that the [default](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redis/redis/7.2/redis.conf) of `maxmemory-policy noeviction` will not even try to remove anything from redis on hitting that limit but just return errors on write operations. Even with other policies, this can still happen (also in that config file):

> Note: with any of the above policies, when there are no suitable keys for
> eviction, Redis will return an error on write operations that require
> more memory.

In short, it's hard to set for existing redis instances and might blow up even on fresh instances when hitting the limit.